# Getting Error/Exception In GoldenGate Replication

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g, goldengate

I am planning to configure a simple GoldenGate configuration and want to implement an exception table that will store all the exceptions. I followed two links, neither of which work for me:

- [Troubleshoot Oracle GoldenGate Using Exception Handler](http://www.vitalsofttech.com/troubleshoot-oracle-goldengate-using-exception-handler)
- [Creating a GoldenGate Exception Handler to Trap and Log Oracle Errors](http://www.oracle11ggotchas.com/articles/CreatingaGoldenGateExceptionHandlertotrapandlogOracleErrors.htm)

#### My Extract Parameter File

```
extract ext9
userid ogg_user, password oracle
rmthost targetGG, mgrport 7809
rmttrail /u01/app/oracle/product/gg_trg/dirdat/np
table scott.emp;
```

#### Replicat File

```
replicat rep9
ASSUMETARGETDEFS
userid ogg_user, password oracle
include ./dirprm/EXCEPTION_HANDLER.mac
REPERROR (DEFAULT, EXCEPTION)
REPERROR (DEFAULT2, ABEND)
REPERROR (-1, EXCEPTION)
MAP scott.emp, TARGET scott.emp;
MAP scott.emp #exception_handler();
```

#### Exception Handler Macro

Created in `./dirprm/EXCEPTION_HANDLER.mac`:

```
MACRO #EXCEPTION_HANDLER
BEGIN
, TARGET GGATE_ADMIN.ALLEXCEPTIONS
, COLMAP ( REPLICAT_NAME = @GETENV("GGENVIRONMENT", "GROUPNAME"))
, TABLE_NAME = @GETENV ("GGHEADER", "TABLENAME")
, ERRNO = @GETENV ("LASTERR", "DBERRNUM")
, DBERRMSG = @GETENV ("LASTERR", "DBERRMSG")
, OPTYPE = @GETENV ("LASTERR", "OPTYPE")
, ERRTYPE = @GETENV ("LASTERR", "ERRTYPE")
, LOGRBA = @GETENV ("GGHEADER", "LOGRBA")
, LOGPOSITION = @GETENV ("GGHEADER", "LOGPOSITION")
, COMMITTIMESTAMP = @GETENV ("GGHEADER", "COMMITTIMESTAMP"))
, INSERTALLRECORDS
, EXCEPTIONSONLY;
END;
```

This is the error I have been getting. I have tried/Googled a lot to get rid of this, finally posting it here for help:

> 2016-06-09 17:18:12  ERROR   OGG-00212  Invalid option for MAP: TABLE_NAME.

I don't know what is causing the problem. I have tried all space issues found on Google and with other bloggers but no success.

Comment: Have you put `include ./dirprm/EXCEPTION_HANDLER.mac` at the top of the replicat file?

Comment: After you specified I tried putting that entry on the top of the file, however same error. What else can be done? Thanks !

Comment: Please help me in this regard.

Comment: I fixed it myself.

Answer (score 1):

There is an error in the code:

```
, COLMAP ( REPLICAT_NAME = @GETENV("GGENVIRONMENT", "GROUPNAME"))
```

There is double bracket at the end of the line.